# Tester returning false when it should be returning true for same name program?

Tags: oop, methods

This is my method

```
       public boolean equals(Name otherName)
       {  
          return (myFirstname.equalsIgnoreCase(otherName)) && (myMiddlename.equalsIgnoreCase(otherName)) && (myLastname.equalsIgnoreCase(otherName));
       }

       public String initials()
       {
          String initials = "";
          initials = myFirstname.substring(0,0) + myMiddlename.substring(0,0) + myLastname.substring(0,0);
          initials.toUpperCase();
          return initials;
       }

       public int length()
       {
          int length;
          length = myFirstname.length() + myMiddlename.length() + myLastname.length();
          return length;
       }


    }
```

And this is my tester

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NameTester
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter your first name.");
      String fname = scanner.nextLine ();
      System.out.println("Enter your middle name.");
      String mname = scanner.nextLine ();
      System.out.println("Enter your last name.");
      String lname = scanner.nextLine ();

      Name namea = new Name(fname,mname,lname);

      System.out.println("Enter your first name.");
      fname = scanner.nextLine ();
      System.out.println("Enter your middle name.");
      mname = scanner.nextLine ();
      System.out.println("Enter your last name.");
      lname = scanner.nextLine ();

      Name nameb = new Name(fname,mname,lname);

      System.out.println("Enter your first name.");
      fname = scanner.nextLine ();
      System.out.println("Enter your middle name.");
      mname = scanner.nextLine ();
      System.out.println("Enter your last name.");
      lname = scanner.nextLine ();

      Name namec = new Name(fname,mname,lname);

          System.out.println(namea.firstMiddleLast());
          System.out.println(namea.lastFirstMiddle());
          System.out.println(namea.initials());
          System.out.println(namea.length());

          System.out.println(nameb.firstMiddleLast());
          System.out.println(nameb.lastFirstMiddle());
          System.out.println(nameb.initials());
          System.out.println(nameb.length());

          System.out.println(namec.firstMiddleLast());
          System.out.println(namec.lastFirstMiddle());
          System.out.println(namec.initials());
          System.out.println(namec.length());

          System.out.println(namea.equals(nameb)); 
          System.out.println(namec.equals(nameb));
          System.out.println(namea.equals(namec)); 
   }
```

for some reason it still outputs false for (namea.equals(nameb)) even though they are the same when I input, i think it has to do with my equals method. Everything else works fine except for when i replace Name with String in the header it compiles and runs with the wrong answer but when I leave it as Name it doesnt even compile

Comment: hows your first name equal to your complete name.. your method surely returns false

Answer (score 0):

what I think your `equals()` method needs to be something like this, so that you can comparing your pieces of name with corresponding pieces of provided name and not with the `Name` object directly

```
public boolean equals(Name otherName)
       {  
          return (myFirstname.equalsIgnoreCase(otherName.firstName)) && (myMiddlename.equalsIgnoreCase(otherName.middleName)) && (myLastname.equalsIgnoreCase(otherName.lastName));
       }
```

Comment: using this method I got a cannot find symbol compilation error (otherName.firstName) what should "firstName" be named the same as should i show my whole class sorry im fairly new to java

Comment: what is your Name class..it does have these three properties fName,mName,lName...isn't it?

Comment: simply put you have to write your equals method in such a way that compares the firstName of namea to the firstName of your argument (i.e. nameb as you have given) and so on...then you will decide either the two names are equal or not

Answer (score 0):

Your equals method is comparing properties of the Name class with the class itself, so basically comparing apples with bananas. You could refactor the Equals method to this:

```
return (myFirstname.equalsIgnoreCase(otherName.FirstName)) && (myMiddlename.equalsIgnoreCase(otherName.MiddleName)) && (myLastname.equalsIgnoreCase(otherName.LastName));
```